# best way to use a for loop using tkinter?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
def draw_cloud (canvas):
    right = 5
    left = 5 
    for i in cloud: 3
        canvas.create_oval(100,110,150, 175, outline = 'white', fill = 'white')
        left += 10
        right += 10
```

for my assignment, I'm using tkinter canvas to draw a scene and trying to figure out how to make my for loop work using tkinter since my assignment requires at least one repetitive element that has to be repeated as a for loop

Comment: What is the goal here? It looks like you are just drawing the same oval 3 times, which would just make them overlap. Plus what is that 3 next to the for i in cloud? And what is cloud, as it's not declared?

Comment: What's the point of the `3` in `for i in cloud: 3` ?

Comment: for this assignment I have to have at least one repetitive element, which I am trying to make a loop to where it creates a certain amount of clouds based on the amount I'm telling it to do. also I do apologize for my confusing code, I've just been trying to build off of the information that was given to me by my TA.  I know how to create each element separately but I just need to figure out how to make it loop

Comment: would it be better if I posted my full code so you guys can see what I'm trying to do with this?

Comment: it would be better if you posted a [mre]

Comment: @KalerSappington: Yes, it would, just follow the guidelines in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks!

Comment: The only thing is that I don’t really know how to reproduce what I’m trying to do

Comment: just provide what you have tried, but so that we can run it too by simply copy-pasting it and so that it is as minimal as can be

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop in this example could work in several ways in your case.

1. Have a list of positions and loop through them using a for loop, and create a cloud there, like:

```
cloud_positions = [(100,110,150,175),(130,140,160,195)]

for position in cloud_positions:
    canvas.create_oval(position[0],position[1],position[2],position[3],outline='white',fill='white')
```

2. Add on to a variable using a for loop:

```
left = 0

for i in range(5): #5 clouds created
    canvas.create_oval(100+left,110,150+left,175)
    left += 400 #next cloud is 400 to the right
```

3. Use the iterate variable:

```
for i in range(5):
    canvas.create_oval(100+i*400,110,150+i*400,175)
```

You should use whatever suits your problem the best. If you want precise control of the clouds position, use the first option. If you just want all the clouds to be relative of each other, use 2 or 3.

Comment: thank you so much for the help @Notebooked